# How to split large dataset into google sitemaps

Tags: xml-sitemap

I'm working on the site and want to create google sitemap efficiently (with images) I have above 30 000 pages and every page have image on them. In every month is about 1000 new pages. (I have also lots of other pages but they don't need to be in sitemap), old pages are not changed very offen but they can be deleted or modified.

I have one sitemap index page and 35 sitemaps in them every sitemap have 1000 pages, (I have limitation, probalby by the framework I use, in the number of results)

Is there better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can read the database and create the image sitemap directly from that, you will need to check out sitemapper solutions that can be scheduled (to run at night = efficient?) and create image sitemaps, e.g. A1 Sitemap Generator (use the image sitemap preset), but there are more tools available if you search Google :)

However, if you have direct access to the database containing both page and image URLs, you may want to program it yourself? That would be the most "efficient method" (i.e reading the database directly)

Comment: Thanks for response but, I mean most efficient from SEO point of view, and google indexing speed, Should I create one sitmap every month or alphabetically, How to split large dataset into google sitemaps, so google will be happy.